# Amazon::SQS::Simple MessageGroupId on a FIFO Queue

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I need help on how to pass the MessageGroupId as parameter using the CPAN Module

[Amazon::SQS::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::SQS::Simple)

I tried the following :

```
my $messageGroupId = 1;
my $q = $sqs->GetQueue('http://queue.amazonaws.com/' . $queue_name);
$q->{MessageGroupId} = $messageGroupId;
$q->SendMessage($message);
```

I also tried putting the MessageGroupId in the $message variable :

```
my $messageGroupId = 1;
my $q = $sqs->GetQueue('http://queue.amazonaws.com/' . $queue_name);
$q->{MessageGroupId} = $messageGroupId;
$q->SendMessage({ MessageGroupId => 1 });
```

But SQS always gives this error :

```
ERROR [try ]: On calling SendMessage: 400 Bad Request (The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @ysth was almost correct; I found the below to work:

```
$q->SendMessage($message, ("MessageGroupId" => 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.  It looks like it is expecting:

```
$q->SendMessage($message, { MessageGroupId => 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to send a message to a FIFO SQS Queue in AWS. But I think

Amazon::SQS::Simple doesn't have support to FIFO Queue.

I end up using [Paws::SQS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::SQS) instead and it's now working